# Humble Bundle build of Vector fails to run on a new install

Tags: technical-issues, humble-bundle, vector

I recently reinstalled Vector, a 2D parkour game, from my Humble Bundle. After installation on my Samsung Galaxy 8, I get a message that the architecture (ARM7A) it uses isn't compatible with my phone's architecture (ARM4T). If I go past that message, I get a prompt asking me to load additional data, but when I try that, it says there there are network issues, and then closes.

I tried installing it on an older tablet, and I don't get the architecture warning, but I still get the failing update prompt.

I am able to install it from the Play Store, but my understanding is that the Play Store version is rigged to require multiple runs on each level to accrue enough points to unlock the next one, as to incentivize buying credits with real money. If that's not true, that's also a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Humble Bundle people and got this response:

> I am sorry to hear the trouble. Unfortunately it appears this title may be out of date for current modern devices to play on. Additionally the developers (Nekki) have shut down and we are not able to provide a new build I am afraid. I apologize for the inconvenience. Should you run into any more issues let me know, otherwise I hope you have a great day!

This does not answer my question fully, but it does indicate that the Humble Bundle version is out-of-date and will remain out-of-date.